# cursor - FETCH next from is not a valid input at this position in loop in MySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor, fetch

How to solve syntax error for FETCH next from cursor into data in **MySQL**?

```
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH next from cur1 INTO id1, userId1, major1,minor1,beaconZone1;
IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
else
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (id1, userId1, major1,minor1,beaconZone1);
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with this code assuming you have it in a stored program and have set delimiters as necessary.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by 'I need to fetch all next rows and compare them with the current row in the cursor' with an example as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH next from cur1 INTO id1, userId1, major1,minor1,beaconZone1;
IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
  CLOSE cursor_name;
else
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (id1, userId1, major1,minor1,beaconZone1);
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: it gives me the same error, even if I close the cursor

Comment: what kind of exception it shows. show me the full code